# Spring-bean default to null if property not set

Tags: xml, spring, spring-bean

I am adding a new property on existing bean but I do not want it on all instance of the bean. 
I did see this option `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` that can be put in

`org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigure`

However this has unintended of consequence if ignoring unset property for all beans defined. Is there a way that I can do either one of these 2 things

1)Tell spring-bean to ignore unset token for a singe type of bean

2)For the bean set a default value which gets over-riden only when  property defined in spring-bean.Since I do not want to add empty property name for all instance of a bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default value to the bean property like below.

In below code it will try to set the property name. If none found it will set "ABC".

```
@Value(value = "${name:ABC}")
private String name;
```

Comment: this is using application.properties file right. I have an older service that uses spring-bean.xml